# How to update select options after option is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select list whose options are based on the selected value. For example, the selected option defaults to 7, and the other four options are always within 2 of this value. So initially `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` are my options.

If a user selects `5` the select options SHOULD update to `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Indeed the POST request tied to `ng-change` fires off successfully and upon page refresh the options are `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. My issue is that these options do not update instantly upon option selection. Page refresh is currently necessary to see this change.

Below is relevant code. Basically I'm looking to force the `maxOptions` array to update instantly upon option selection.

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="option for option in linked.maxOptions" ng-model="linked.selectedMax" ng-change="linked.changeMax()"></select>
```

Controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.maxOptions = [];

var getplayerInfo = function() {
  playersService.getPlayerInfo({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(player) {
    vm.player = player;
    for (var i = player.max_points - 2; i < customer.max_points + 3; i++) {
      vm.maxOptions.push(i);
    }
    vm.selectedMax = player.max_points;
  });
};

var init = function() {
  getplayerInfo();
};

init();

vm.changeMax = function() {
  playersService.setMaxPoints({
    playerId: playerId,
    max: vm.selectedMax
  }, {}).$promise.then(function(res){
    return res.success;
  }, function(res) {
    alert('Couldn\'t update number of points to ' + vm.selectedMax + ':' + res.success);
  });
};
```

I'm thinking I need to do something within the `$promise` resolution in order to update the UI instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maxOptions` array is only updated in `getplayerInfo` which is called in `init`. There is no code to update the `maxOptions` when you call `changeMax`. Therefore `maxOptions` only gets set on page load but not on change.

You need to do something like this in your changeMax.

```
vm.changeMax = function() {
  playersService.setMaxPoints({
    playerId: playerId,
    max: vm.selectedMax
  }, {}).$promise.then(function(res){
    vm.player.max_points = vm.selectedMax;
    vm.maxOptions = [];
    for (var i = player.max_points - 2; i < customer.max_points + 3; i++) {
      vm.maxOptions.push(i);
    }
    return res.success;
  }, function(res) {
    alert('Couldn\'t update number of points to ' + vm.selectedMax + ':' + res.success);
  });
};
```

Or better yet, abstract the building of the array as a model method like this and call it from both functions:

```
vm.updateMaxOptions = function() {
        vm.maxOptions = [];
        for (var i = player.max_points - 2; i < customer.max_points + 3; i++) {
          vm.maxOptions.push(i);
        }
};

vm.changeMax = function() {
  playersService.setMaxPoints({
    playerId: playerId,
    max: vm.selectedMax
  }, {}).$promise.then(function(res){
    vm.player.max_points = vm.selectedMax;
    vm.updateMaxOptions();
    return res.success;
  }, function(res) {
    alert('Couldn\'t update number of points to ' + vm.selectedMax + ':' + res.success);
  });
};
```

Comment: Any advice on how to best update this array within the `$promise` resolution? Also, is updating the array enough to update the UI as well? I'm guessing so due to two-way data-binding.

Comment: @MattDionis Updated post with code snippet. Yes, updating the array will update the DOM too, that's the angular way. If it doesn't then perhaps post a plunker so we can take a look.